# converting a .mat file with table to a .mat file with cell array

Tags: matlab

I need to convert a .mat file that contains a variable 't' of the type table to a cell. This is because there is another code that reads a cell array and performs str2num and char functions on it. When the code uses the str2num and char functions on the table that needs conversion it throws an error " Error using char : Conversion to char from table is not possible ". Is there anyway I can convert the format of a .mat file(with a table) to the format of a different .mat file(containing cell arrays) so that the code written for the.mat files with cell arrays works for the .mat file with table?

Comment: Did you try reading in the file, converting the table to a cell, and writing to a new file?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer this question. 
First let us create a table with numbers as cellstrings and save this table as a .mat file.

```
TestNumbersAsString = {'42', '500', '288'}';
t = table(TestNumbersAsString);
save('myTable.mat', 't');
```

Let us clear our workspace and load the file. convert the table to a cell and save this cell as a .mat file. Load this file again.

```
clearvars t
load('myTable.mat');
tAsCell = table2cell(t);
save('myCell.mat', 'tAsCell');
clearvars tAsCell
load('myCell.mat');
```

Convert and print the first element in the cell.

```
display(str2num(tAsCell{1}))
```

We could have used also the table.

```
display(str2num(t{1,1}{1}))
```

EDIT: 
please share an example and explain what you really want. You have never mentioned the column labels or NaN values.

`tAsCellWithLabel = [t.Properties.VariableNames;  table2cell(t)];`

And you can remove the NaN values or check for NaN values and never call the function "str2num", if the cell value is NaN.
Check the "isnan" function.
There are so many ways to solve it.
But I do not know whats your data and how you want to use the data.

Comment: This works but the lables of the table(column names) are not getting copied into the cell from the table.

Comment: Also, display(str2num(tAsCell{1})) is 0

Comment: My table has NaN and ' ' on the table elements.

Comment: I need to convert a table in matlab to cellstr. This table has NaN values. I tried to remove the NaN and I am unable to. When I do table2cell, it converts to a cell but not cellstr. iscellstr(t) returns 0. Also the converted cell has ' ' around the column names. I need to use this data on a different program that accepts cell type. When I use the .mat file that has a table, it throws an error saying conversion to char from table is not possible. the program also does not allow me to to perform str2num on the table. previous Cellstr type is working fine with the program.